# How can I model conditionals based on join tables in jpa / hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to teach myself hibernate by making a pointless app that has a list of my local pubs which users can mark visited or not, so basically a fancy tick list.

If I was writing this with raw sql I'd have a table of pubs, a table of users and a join table linking the ids from the other two tables for cases were a pub has been marked visited for a particular user.

The query I'd use to fetch the complete list with the visited status for a specified user would be something like this (in postgres)

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN up.id IS null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS visited 
FROM pubs p  
LEFT JOIN users_pub up ON p.id = up.pubId
```

I'm trying to figure out how to go about annotating my model classes to get this visited property to appear. Ideas?

The hibernate docs can be a quite unwieldy for a beginner so even a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to model this would be a `User` class that has a `@ManytoMany` collection of `Pub`, so you could read a user and fetch the collection of pubs they've visited.

Then it would be easy enough to implement a method on User like:

```
hasVisitedPub(id)
```

that returns true if the that pub is in their `pubsVisited` collection.

Use a `Map<id, Pub>` if you want to make the lookup more efficient for people who've visited a large number of pubs, as they should :-)